# Google Play Leaderboards Limits

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-games, leaderboard

I made a game for android with leaderboards in it, and the game is already published.
I set a limit to avoid scores greater then a certain number.
Now i would like to remove those limitations, but there is a lock with this message:
"This field cannot be changed after publishing."

Google let me modify the value, it is allowed, but the question is: will i lose all the scores in my leaderboard? 
The official documentation it is not clear.

Comment: Could you please provide links to the documentation you are referring to?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards
it says i can modify any field, ant that's correct, but some of them have the lock, some not...i want to know if modify the locked one resets the leaderboard

Comment: Sorry to revive the old thread but has anyone found a solution around this? Thanks!